# Bootstrap centering of button not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i tried to center a row of bootstrap custom buttons. It is not working and still is at the left side of the page, no matter what i try. i need some help.
the page got all bootstrap added to the code like it should, but i cant center this buttons. Thank you.
Here is my css and html Code

```
<style type="text/css">
 .btn-circle {

      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
      line-height: 1.428571429;
      border-radius: 130px;
    }


    .btn-circle.btn-lg {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.33;
      border-radius: 130px;
      border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
    }
    .btn-circle.btn-xl {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 1.33;
      border-radius: 130px;
     border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
    }

</style>

    <div class="row" style="margin:auto;text-align:center;">

    <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to make the buttons centered or the row?

Comment: tldr but it's proably something to do with all the floats going on in bs.. try clearing floats first

Comment: All buttons are centered in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bL8vr504/ (With your original code, didn't change anything)

Comment: yes they should be all centered to the center of the row - next to each other with the margin of the .col-lg-2

Comment: If you'd be willing it'd help to make a Stack Snippet for this so that there is a reproducible example. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: whatever you need to help me - if we can help others with this... sounds awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your codes. --

```css
 .btn-circle {

      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
      line-height: 1.428571429;
      border-radius: 130px;
    }


    .btn-circle.btn-lg {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.33;
      border-radius: 130px;
      border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .btn-circle.btn-xl {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 1.33;
      border-radius: 130px;
     border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="row" style="margin:auto;text-align:center;">

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
</div>
```

Solution of overlapping problem. --

```css
.btn-circle {

      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
      line-height: 1.428571429;
      border-radius: 130px;
    }


    .btn-circle.btn-lg {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.33;
      border-radius: 130px;
      border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .btn-circle.btn-xl {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 1.33;
      border-radius: 130px;
     border:7px solid #cfd8dc;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12"  style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice... you fixed it. Thanks so much
Have you got an idea how i can do it that they stay in a row longer if i crop the window? the flap down now pretty quick.

Comment: just replace the 'col-lg-2' by 'col-xs-2' and 'col-lg-offset-2' by 'col-xs-offset-2'. This will keep them in a line for all kind of devices. Even on mobile. If you want to avoid mobile, use 'col-sm-2' instead of 'col-lg-2'

Comment: yeah it works better, but it now overlaps even if there is not enough room. i tried to use them both, but that doesn't work either

Comment: By default bootstrap's col-* have some padding of 15px each on left and right. Plus, your button's have a fixed width, so for extra small devices they'll overlaps.

Comment: but isnt there a way that the stay in a row as long as possible til they overlaps?

Comment: @Crag, updated the answer. Now you've solution for both issue. 2nd snippet is for keep them in a row as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the unnecessary div wrap around each button, then the text-align works properly.  Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bL8vr504/1/

```
<div class="row" style="margin:auto;text-align:center; width: 100%;">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button>

</div>
```

final note, apply any needed margin on one of the button classes.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add **col-lg-offset-2** to your first column

You don't need     `style="margin:auto;text-align:center;"`

Or you also can do something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
<div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2">  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><span>-</span></button></div>
<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `<div class="col-lg-2">`  with `<div class="col-lg-2 text-center">`

Normally it works
Regards
*Nabeel*